# How to rsync a large directory tree, but only leaf directories that match a regex?

Tags: rsync, directory-structure

This is easier to explain with an example. Imagine I have a directory structure as follows:

```
pics/cats/png/01.png
pics/cats/png/02.png
pics/cats/jpg/01.jpg
pics/cats/jpg/02.jpg
pics/dogs/png/01.png
pics/dogs/png/02.png
pics/dogs/jpg/01.jpg
pics/dogs/jpg/02.jpg
```

I would like to rsync the "pics" directory to a destination, but on the destination I would like the following result, assuming the filter string for my leaf directories is "png":

```
pics/cats/png/01.png
pics/cats/png/02.png
pics/dogs/png/01.png
pics/dogs/png/02.png
```

In addition, I would like to accomplish the following result as well: (as the png dirs are no longer necessary)

```
pics/cats/01.png
pics/cats/02.png
pics/dogs/01.png
pics/dogs/02.png
```

It might be important to note that any directory might have the string "png" in it, but I only want to "filter" on the leaf directories, ie, directories that do not contain another directory.

It might be important to note also that I want to keep the contents of the "png" directories, even if they contain non-png files. Ie:

```
pics/cats/png/01.png
pics/cats/png/02.txt
pics/cats/jpg/01.jpg
pics/cats/jpg/02.jpg
pics/dogs/png/01.txt
pics/dogs/png/02.png
pics/dogs/jpg/01.jpg
pics/dogs/jpg/02.jpg
```

Becomes:

```
pics/cats/png/01.png
pics/cats/png/02.txt
pics/dogs/png/01.txt
pics/dogs/png/02.png
```

Or:

```
pics/cats/01.png
pics/cats/02.txt
pics/dogs/01.txt
pics/dogs/02.png
```

Last item to note: The directory structure might be "n" deep. Ie:

```
pics/cats/house/tabby/png/01.png
pics/cats/house/tabby/png/02.txt
pics/cats/house/tabby/jpg/01.jpg
pics/cats/house/tabby/jpg/02.jpg
```

Becomes:

```
pics/cats/house/tabby/png/01.png
pics/cats/house/tabby/png/02.txt
```

Or:

```
pics/cats/house/tabby/01.png
pics/cats/house/tabby/02.txt
```

If no easy way exists I'm sure I can just write a bash script to do it, but this seems like a use case that while not common, I'm sure crops up every now and then, and perhaps there is a name and flag for this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [get all the leaf nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574403/list-all-leaf-subdirectories-in-linux), filter them with `grep` and save the result to a file.

Then you run `rsync` with the `--files-from` option.

That is just the basics. You could filter directly in `awk` and/or pipe directly to to `xargs` for example. I'm not trying to be concise or performant, but to show the steps involved.

If you are at the root of the hierarchy:

```
$ find . -type d | sort | awk '$0 !~ last "/" {print last} {last=$0} END {print last}' | grep '/png$' > /tmp/dirs_rsync.txt

$ rsync -av --files-from=/tmp/dirs_rsync.txt . /your/destination/folder
```

Comment: Does anybody care to explain the downvotes? Is there something wrong with the answer?

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. (FWIW I upvoted also)

Comment: The issue with this answer is related to the fact that names of directories may contain newlines. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697